# Lazy Loading using Updatepanel and Timer in C#

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

After loading updatepanel through Timer, i am unable to make any async request from the updatepanel.

sample aspx Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

    <%--The Timer that causes the partial postback--%>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="100" OnTick="Timer_Tick" Id="Timer1"/>                

    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSaveEmployeePrevJobs" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsBottom"
    ImageUrl="~/Images/saveOff.gif" onmouseout="this.src='../Images/saveOff.gif'"
    onmouseover="this.src='../Images/saveOn.gif'" OnClick="btnSaveEmployeePrevJobs_Click"/>

</ContentTemplate>
```

Server Side Code:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    //some code
}

protected void btnSaveEmployeePrevJobs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code
}
```

> Problem : unable to raise click event
>   on button click, basically Timer gets
>   enabled (don't know why) and it call
>   itself again instead of calling click
>   event ..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i have resolved my prob, it was a conflict between viewstate (storing viewstate in session) and the async requests... It was giving the new no. to viewstates on postback.

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery instead, cause I think 100 milliseconds is VERY small so your server side code may be still loading and get executed, after the timer ticks for more 2 times or so.

load your DOM, write a simple jQuery function to fetch your data from your server, fill it inside your page, then smile :)

Comment: I am just optimizing the existing code, which is build on updatepanels so using jquery will be a huge change.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Timer1.Enabled = false;
    Label1.Text = "Panel refreshed at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

Note that, if you are setting `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, you need to call `UpdatePanel.Update()` explicitly; otherwise remove the attribute.

Checkout: [Tutorial: How to refresh an UpdatePanel control at a timed interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx#Y798)